# Two ways of rotating 3D point, What is the difference

Tags: c#, math, geometry

I need to rotate a 3D point round the Y-axis

I'm no matematician so I have searched the internet and found this page
https://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/modeling/mod_tran/3drota.htm#Y-Axis%20Rotation

Using this code

```
private void RotateAroundY_1()
{
    double x = 40.46;
    double y = 16.52;
    double z = 56.5;
    double b = -1* 64.77;       // rotation degree (mult with -1 to get the rotation counter clockwise

    double B = DegreeToRadian(b);   // B


    double X = x * Math.Cos(B) + z*Math.Sin(B);
    double Y = y;
    double Z = z*Math.Cos(B) - x*Math.Sin(B);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("X: {0} Y: {1} Z: {2}",X,Y,Z));
}
private double DegreeToRadian(double b)
{
    return (Math.PI / 180) * b;
}
```

I get this result

```
X: -33,8639291270836 
Y: 16,52 
Z: 60,6835719455922
```

BUT, the rotated coordinates should be (according to the 3D CAD program and its user)

```
X: 68.38
Y: 16,52 
Z: -12.5
```

If I use this code

```
private void RotateAroundY_2()
{
    double x = 40.46;
    double y = 16.52;
    double z = 56.5;
    double b = -1* 64.77;   // rotation degree (mult with -1 to get the rotation counter clockwise

    double curAng = Math.Atan2(z, x);
    double X = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(z, 2));
    double Y = Math.Cos(DegreeToRadian(b) + curAng) * hyp;
    double Z = Math.Sin(DegreeToRadian(b) + curAng) * hyp;

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("X: {0} Y: {1} Z: {2}",X,Y,Z));
}
private double DegreeToRadian(double b)
{
    return (Math.PI / 180) * b;
}
```

I get this result

```
X: 68,3563218478633
Y: 16,52
Z: -12,5169830003609
```

So I'm going to use the RotateAroundY_2, but I wish I could understand what the difference are and why I 
should use the second one?

ELI5 (Explain Like I'm five)

Comment: @user1444 minus sign on the other side is OK from math point (it just change the direction of rotation) but as OP wants to mimic a specific behavior its a bug. You can comments your own posts. On the other ones you need some reputation first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you got the `-` sign wrong it should be on the other sinus... I do not code in **C#** so all the code chunks are in **C++** (need to port it but that shoul dbe simple enough).

```cpp
void rotate_y(double &x,double &y,double &z,double ang)
    {
    double u=x,v=z;
    ang*=M_PI/180.0;
    x=+u*cos(ang)-v*sin(ang);
    z=+u*sin(ang)+v*cos(ang);
    }
```

using it like this:

```cpp
double x=40.46,y=16.52,z=56.5,ang=-64.77;
mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("(%03.3f,%03.3f,%03.3f)",x,y,z));
rotate_y(x,y,z,ang);
mm_log->Lines->Add(AnsiString().sprintf("(%03.3f,%03.3f,%03.3f)",x,y,z));
```

results in this output:

```
(40.460,16.520,56.500)
(68.356,16.520,-12.517)
```

When you got the minus on the other `sin` then you are rotating the other way around so multiplying angle by `-1` will lead to your wanted result too.

```cpp
void rotate_y(double &x,double &y,double &z,double ang)
    {
    double u=x,v=z;
    ang*=-M_PI/180.0;       
    x=+u*cos(ang)+v*sin(ang);
    z=-u*sin(ang)+v*cos(ang);
    }
```

like this:

```
(40.460,16.520,56.500)
(68.356,16.520,-12.517)
```

You can also optimized the rotation a bit:

```cpp
void rotate_y(double &x,double &y,double &z,double ang)
    {
    double u=x,v=z,c,s;
    ang*=M_PI/180.0;
    c=cos(ang);
    s=sin(ang);
    x=+u*c-v*s;
    z=+u*s+v*c;
    }
```

to avoid multiple `sin,cos` usage.

The other rotation code you got is very slow and inaccurate as it relays on `atan2` (that has also the potential danger of getting `NaN` in subresults). It simply converts your point into polar coordinates add the delta angle and convert back to cartesian.

Comment: Oh, is my face red! Seems like a translation error from the math formula to C#. I will blame it on some phone call interupting ;-) Thank you very much!!